# TKinter threading - how to return a value with a progress bar

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter, progress-bar

I am trying to display a progress bar, while the bckground process is running. No problems with that, everything worked (I did it different way). But this background process needs to return a value, and that's where I get stack. If I use other topic's suggestions, I have an error

> runtime error main thread is not in main loop

Now I understand that TKinter allows windows (and widgets) to be run in a main loop only. Then how do I wrap my progress bar in thread? Would be nice to be able to change a message too, when the process is finished. I am trying to avoid using global variables, but is this the only option I have?
I passed "progress" or "master" or other widgets as variables to my threading function, but that didn't work either (same error)

This is my modified code (note, var1, var2, var3 are just variables I need to pass for background process. They are important for a return result):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
from queue import Queue

def my_window(var1, var2, var3):
    myList = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.geometry("600x250+350+100")    
    
    msg1 = tk.Message(master, text="Please wait...Something is happening.", anchor='w', width = 500)
    msg1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.6)  

    progress = ttk.Progressbar(master)
    progress.config(mode='determinate', maximum=100, value=0)
    progressStep = 100/len(myList)        
    
    que = Queue()
    t = threading.Thread(target = lambda q, *args: q.put(threading_function(*args)), args=(que, var1, var2, var3))
    #t.setDaemon(True) - saw this suggestion on other topic, didn't work for me
    t.start() 
    result = que.get()
    master.mainloop()   
    return result

def threading_function(var1, var2, var3):
    progress.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.1)
    

    for item in myList:
        #do some background processes - takes few seconds each
        progress.step(progressStep)
     #importantVariable = result of what was happening
        
    msg1.place_forget()
    msg2 = tk.Message(master, text="The process is finished.", anchor='w', width = 500).place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.6)         
    button_Continue = tk.Button(master, text='Continue', command = master.destroy)
    button_Continue.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.15)              
    progress.place_forget()
    # return importantVariable
```

And this is the code that worked before, but no option to return a value at all (returns None). It works without passing variables:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import threading

def my_window(var1, var2, var3):
    myList = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
    master = tk.Tk()
    master.geometry("600x250+350+100")    
    
    msg1 = tk.Message(master, text="Please wait...Something is happening.", anchor='w', width = 500)
    msg1.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.6)  

    progress = ttk.Progressbar(master)
    progress.config(mode='determinate', maximum=100, value=0)
    progressStep = 100/len(myList)        
    
    def threading_function():
        progress.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6, relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.1)
        

        for item in myList:
            #do some background processes - takes few seconds each
            progress.step(progressStep)
        #importantVariable = result of what was happening
            
        msg1.place_forget()
        msg2 = tk.Message(master, text="The process is finished.", anchor='w', width = 500).place(relx=0.1, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.6)         
        button_Continue = tk.Button(master, text='Continue', command = master.destroy)
        button_Continue.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.8, relwidth=0.2, relheight=0.15)              
        progress.place_forget()
        return importantVariable      
    
    
    threading.Thread(target = threading_function).start()
    master.mainloop()   
    return importantVariable #returns None, which is not what I need
```

So the questin (again) is, how do I return a result from a thread, while using progress bar (and preferabbly other TKinter widgets too)?
Thank you

Comment: Just don't return a variable. Instead, put the variable in the queue and have a function to digest your queue using `after` method.

Comment: @HenryYik thank you, could you explain little more, please? I never worked with Queues before this. Or link would do. What do you mean by "digest"?